# Compiling amd64 binary on i386 root with amd64 kernel (Debian)

Tags: c++, linux, 64-bit, debian

I have a rather old Debian testing system that has all packages installed as i386. Usually I'm running a PAE kernel (linux-image-3.16.0-4-686-pae:i386).

I'm trying to compile a simple C++ program that needs more than 4 GB of memory. I've installed the linux-image-3.16.0-4-amd64:amd64 kernel because I think it is not possible to get more than 3GB of memory on a PAE machine.

Unfortunately, the whole toolchain/libraries are still i386. I guess I need a special flavour of GCC (multilib?) and the amd64 version of some libraries.

I've found tutorials on how to compile 32bit stuff on 64bit rootfs systems, but not the other way round. I don't want to cross-grade the whole system to amd64 just for this test, so:

Is there a way to safely compile and run 64bit code on this setup with as little changes to the system as necessary? Ideally it would be possible to cross-grade from this setup at some point in the future. Alternately, would it be possible to create a 64bit chroot environment from a Debian Live CD, chroot into it, compile the code and run it from there? Or compile it statically and run it outside the chroot?

**EDIT:** Installing g++multilib solves the problem compiling 64bit (using the `-m64` option). Can anyone help with the chroot / cross-grade part of my question?

Comment: It's about 14 or so years since I did this, but I believe that if your compiler supports the -m64 option, you should be able to do what you are looking to do by simply installing the libraries (when I did this, I had to build the C runtime library myself, build the compiler myself, and build the OS myself - but then I did in the process manage to be the very first person in the world [by a few hours] to run an Linux on an SMP x86-64-machine (at AMD in Austin, TX where I was working at the time, "on loan" from the AMD office in England)]

Comment: That sounds like a big adventure and a lot of work back then ... :-} I'll try installing some libraries in amd64 flavour and see where this ends.